# Visualising the vector space of scaled rotations in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, soft-question, rotations, visualization

Recently I have learned that scaled rotations in $2$ dimensions form a vector space.

One way to see this is to verfiy that a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ is a scaled rotation if and only if $\operatorname{cof} A=A$ where $\operatorname{cof} A$ is the [cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$.
(Note that $\operatorname{cof} A$ is linear in $A$).

However, I find it hard to visualise that a sum of rotations is again (a scaled) rotation. (I do not have a "feeling" to what the resulting angle will be as a function of the original angles).

If we denote the original angles by $\theta, \tilde \theta$, and by $\alpha$ the resulting angle, then (see calculation below)
$$ \cos \alpha = \frac{\cos(\theta)+\cos(\tilde \theta)}{\sqrt{2\big(1+\cos(\theta-\tilde \theta)\big)}}, \sin \alpha = \frac{\sin(\theta)+\sin(\tilde \theta)}{\sqrt{2\big(1+\cos(\theta-\tilde \theta)\big)}}$$

**Question: Is there a nice way to visualizse this phenomena?**

I guess we can plot $\alpha(\theta,\tilde \theta) = \arctan(\frac{\sin(\theta)+\sin(\tilde \theta)}{\cos(\theta)+\cos(\tilde \theta)})$ in some domain, but this wil not give the whole behaviour since $\arctan$ has a domain which is limited by $\pi$.

**Another relevant question is what is the dimension of the space of scaled rotations (which we denote by $W$)?** *How does a basis for $W$ looks like?*

It is trivial to see that $\dim W \ge 2$ (there are two linearly independent rotations). Since not every matrix is a scaled rotation, we also get $\dim W \le 3$.

---

**Calculations:**

Consider the following: Let $ R_{\theta} = \begin{pmatrix} c & -s \\  s & c \end{pmatrix}, R_{\tilde \theta} = \begin{pmatrix} \tilde c & -\tilde s \\  \tilde s & \tilde c  \\  \end{pmatrix}$ be two rotation matrices. We exrpess their sum as a scaled rotation:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \tilde c + c & -(\tilde s + s) \\  \tilde s+s & \tilde c+c  \\  \end{pmatrix} = R_{\theta} + R_{\tilde \theta} = \lambda R_{\alpha}= \lambda \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\  b & a \end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$ \lambda^2 = (\lambda a)^2+(\lambda b)^2= (\tilde c + c)^2 + (\tilde s + s)^2=2(1+c\tilde c+s \tilde s).$$

Noting that $c\tilde c+s \tilde s=\cos(\theta)\cos(\tilde \theta)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\tilde \theta)=\cos(\theta-\tilde \theta)$, we get that

$$ \lambda(\theta,\tilde \theta) = \sqrt{2\big(1+\cos(\theta-\tilde \theta)\big)}$$

This makes sens! The closer the angles are to each other, the behaviour is more like "constructive interference" so the scaling gets larger.

We can also obtain:

$$ \cos \alpha = \frac{\cos(\theta)+\cos(\tilde \theta)}{\lambda(\theta,\tilde \theta)}, \sin \alpha = \frac{\sin(\theta)+\sin(\tilde \theta)}{\lambda(\theta,\tilde \theta)}$$

Comment: “Scaled rotation” matrices are also known as *conformal* matrices. Under multiplication, they’re isomorphic to complex numbers. Perhaps this isomorphism carries over to addition as well?

Comment: You are right of course. I think the isomorphism *does* carriy over to addition.

Comment: For me the easiest way to visualize this is to consider what happens to the unit vector $(1,0)$, because its image determines how every other point transforms as well. Addition of transformations is then simply vector addition. (Of course, the image interpreted as a complex number is precisely the complex number the transformation is isomorphic to.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $A=\operatorname{cof}A$ means that we’re dealing with matrices of the form $\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}$, the so-called *conformal* matrices. These matrices can be identified with the complex numbers, and addition of these matrices is good old vector addition in $\mathbb R^2$ in disguise. If you carry through with the computations that you’ve started, you’ll have reconstructed polar formulas for vector/complex-number addition. (There’s a nice discussion of such formulas in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365622/265466).)

A natural basis for this space is $I=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, $J=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$, which correspond to $1$ and $i$, respectively.

Comment: You are right, of course! The key point is that these matrices are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

Comment: One more thing: Every scaled rotation is conformal, but not vice versa, take for example $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$.  Scaled rotations are exactly orientation preserving conformal matrices (i.e positive determinant).

Comment: @AsafShachar Good point. The definition of conformal that I had learned was more restricted, but I see now that it includes all angle-preserving maps. I would say non-negative determinant, though. You can’t have a vector space without a zero, and we’re still using normal matrix addition for this space.

Comment: You are right. Actually, after talking with a colleague, it turns out that perhaps the convention that conformal maps are orientation preserving is more popular than the other. Doesn't really matter anyway... Thanks again.